# Android Wear app crashing with FATAL EXCEPTION: IntentService[CalendarQueryService]

Tags: android, wear-os

I've been looking for others suffering the same issue but can't seem to find any posts.

Anyway, I've been using the LG G watch with my Nexus 5 but after a few days, the Android Wear app crashes continuously i.e. I keep getting 'Android Wear has stopped unexpectedly' dialogs over and over again. It gets to the point where I have to uninstall the Wear app, thus making wearing the G watch pretty pointless! Reinstalling the app straight away results in the same. I reinstalled the app after a few days (and saw an update had been pushed) and it was fine but a couple of days later: the same thing happened.

The logcat output shows:

> E/DatabaseUtils( 8642): Writing exception to parcel E/DatabaseUtils(
>   8642): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: the bind value at index 1
>   is null E/DatabaseUtils( 8642):   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.bindString(SQLiteProgram.java:164)
>   E/DatabaseUtils( 8642):   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.bindAllArgsAsStrings(SQLiteProgram.java:200)
>   E/DatabaseUtils( 8642):   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:47)
>   E/DatabaseUtils( 8642):   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1314)
>   E/DatabaseUtils( 8642):   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder.query(SQLiteQueryBuilder.java:400)
>   E/DatabaseUtils( 8642):   at
>   com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2.query(ContactsProvider2.java:6440)
>   E/DatabaseUtils( 8642):   at
>   com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2.queryLocal(ContactsProvider2.java:6388)
>   E/DatabaseUtils( 8642):   at
>   com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2.query(ContactsProvider2.java:4996)
>   E/DatabaseUtils( 8642):   at
>   android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.query(ContentProvider.java:200)
>   E/DatabaseUtils( 8642):   at
>   android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:112)
>   E/DatabaseUtils( 8642):   at
>   android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:404)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(11842): FATAL EXCEPTION:
>   IntentService[CalendarQueryService] E/AndroidRuntime(11842): Process:
>   com.google.android.wearable.app, PID: 11842 E/AndroidRuntime(11842):
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: the bind value at index 1 is null
>   E/AndroidRuntime(11842):  at
>   android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:167)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(11842):  at
>   android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:137)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(11842):  at
>   android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:413)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(11842):  at
>   android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:461)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(11842):  at
>   android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:404)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(11842):  at
>   com.google.android.clockwork.contact.ContactInfoUtil.queryContactInfoByEmail(ContactInfoUtil.java:49)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(11842):  at
>   com.google.android.clockwork.calendar.CalendarUtils.queryContactsForAttendeesAndOwnerAccounts(CalendarUtils.java:281)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(11842):  at
>   com.google.android.clockwork.calendar.CalendarUtils.queryCalendarEventInstances(CalendarUtils.java:202)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(11842):  at
>   com.google.android.clockwork.calendar.CalendarQueryService.onHandleIntent(CalendarQueryService.java:99)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(11842):  at
>   android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(11842):  at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(11842):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(11842):  at
>   android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)

Being the actual Android Wear app, I'm not sure what I can do to fix the issue. Any suggestions please?

Thanks.

Comment: I've noticed that quite a few people have these due to an exchange account on the device. Not sure what the problem is, but removing the exchange account stops this crash.

Answer (score 1):

Two or three weeks ago I had a similar situation where the Android Wear app would crash multiple times very day with an `IllegalArgumentException`.

I tried removing the Android Wear app, resetting the watch (Moto 360), re-pairing, removing a lot of the app from the watch, all that kind of stuff, multiple times but nothing helped.

In the end I **wiped the cache partition of my phone** (Nexus 4) and that seems to have **fixed the issue**.

Android Wear hasn't crashed anymore in the past two or three weeks (#FingersCrossed)

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing up Calendar Storage app (Force Stop + Clear Data). This resolved my problem on Nexus 5 (Lollipop 5.0)